# System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1") throws PlatformNotSupportedException?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

See subject, note that this question only applies to the .NET **compact** framework. This happens on the emulators that ship with Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK as well as on my English HTC Touch Pro (all .NET CF 3.5). iso-8859-1 stands for Western European (ISO), which is probably the most important encoding besides us-ascii (at least when one goes by the number of usenet posts).

I'm having a hard time to understand why this encoding is not supported, while the following ones are supported (again on both the emulators & my HTC):

- iso-8859-2 (Central European (ISO))
- iso-8859-3 (Latin 3 (ISO))
- iso-8859-4 (Baltic (ISO))
- iso-8859-5 (Cyrillic (ISO))
- iso-8859-7 (Greek (ISO))

So, is support for say Greek more important than support for German, French 
and Spanish? Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Andreas

Answer (score 15):

I would try to use "windows-1252" as encoding string. [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), Windows-1252 is a superset of ISO-8859-1.

```
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)
```

Comment: Hi

This approach is very cumbersome in some situations, e.g. when you have an XML stream with a ISO-8859-1 encoding. You'd need to replace the encoding "iso-8859-1" with "windows-1252" before feeding it to the XML reader.

Answer (score 7):

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5b31f9d.aspx) says:

> The .NET Compact Framework supports
>   character encoding on all devices:
>   Unicode (BE and LE), UTF8, UTF7, and
>   ASCII.
>
> There is limited support for code page
>   encoding and only if the encoding is
>   recognized by the operating system of
>   the device.
>
> The .NET Compact Framework throws a
>   PlatformNotSupportedException if the a
>   required encoding is not available on
>   the device.

I believe all (or at least many) of the ISO encodings are code-page encodings and fall under the "limited support" rule. UTF8 is probably your best bet as a replacement.

Comment: Hi

It seems none of the linked pages contain information that could answer the question "Why is ISO-8859-7 supported while ISO-8859-1 isn't?"

Comment: I thought the "limited support for code page supporting" wrapped it up rather succinctly, myself. I believe you're stuck with using UTF8.

Answer (score 5):

I know its a bit later but I made an implementation for .net cf of encoding ISO-8859-1, I hope this could help:

```
namespace System.Text
{
    public class Latin1Encoding : Encoding
    {
        private readonly string m_specialCharset = (char) 0xA0 + @"¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ";

        public override string WebName
        {
            get { return @"ISO-8859-1"; }
        }

        public override int CodePage
        {
            get { return 28591; }
        }

        public override int GetByteCount(char[] chars, int index, int count)
        {
            return count;
        }

        public override int GetBytes(char[] chars, int charIndex, int charCount, byte[] bytes, int byteIndex)
        {
            if (chars == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(@"chars", @"null array");
            if (bytes == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(@"bytes", @"null array");
            if (charIndex < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(@"charIndex");
            if (charCount < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(@"charCount");
            if (chars.Length - charIndex < charCount)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(@"chars");
            if (byteIndex < 0 || byteIndex > bytes.Length)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(@"byteIndex");

            for (int i = 0; i < charCount; i++)
            {
                char ch = chars[charIndex + i];
                int chVal = ch;
                bytes[byteIndex + i] = chVal < 160 ? (byte)ch : (chVal <= byte.MaxValue ? (byte)m_specialCharset[chVal - 160] : (byte)63);
            }

            return charCount;
        }

        public override int GetCharCount(byte[] bytes, int index, int count)
        {
            return count;
        }

        public override int GetChars(byte[] bytes, int byteIndex, int byteCount, char[] chars, int charIndex)
        {
            if (chars == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(@"chars", @"null array");
            if (bytes == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(@"bytes", @"null array");
            if (byteIndex < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(@"byteIndex");
            if (byteCount < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(@"byteCount");
            if (bytes.Length - byteIndex < byteCount)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(@"bytes");
            if (charIndex < 0 || charIndex > chars.Length)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(@"charIndex");

            for (int i = 0; i < byteCount; ++i)
            {
                byte b = bytes[byteIndex + i];
                chars[charIndex + i] = b < 160 ? (char)b : m_specialCharset[b - 160];
            }

            return byteCount;
        }

        public override int GetMaxByteCount(int charCount)
        {
            return charCount;
        }

        public override int GetMaxCharCount(int byteCount)
        {
            return byteCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is odd that 8859-1 isn't supported, but that said, UTF-8 does have the ability to represent all of teh 8859-1 characters (and more), so  is there a reason you can't just use UTF-8 instead? That's what we do internally, and I just dealt with almost this same issue today.  The plus side of using UTF-8 is that you get support for far-east and cyrillic languages without making modifications and without adding weight to the western languages.

Comment: I don't see how UTF-8 "contains" iso-8859-1. In the former, only pure ASCII characters can be encoded in one byte, in the latter also chars like e.g. Ä can be encoded in one byte. So if you have a file encoded in ISO-8859-1 you cannot correctly read it with the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Ah, I see - you have text already encoded. I was thinking that you simply needed a mechanism for encoding all of these chanracters

Comment: Looks like you'll be manually converting the files, then. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is getting an exception(.NET compact framework) like:

```
 System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(“iso-8859-1”) throws PlatformNotSupportedException,

//Please follow the steps: 

   byte[] bytes=Encoding.Default.GetBytes(yourText.ToString);

//The code is:

    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(FullfileName); //file type :  *.text,*.xml 
    string yourText = (char) 0xA0 + @"¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ";

    using (FileStream s = fileInfo.OpenWrite()) {
                        s.Write(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(yourText.ToString()), 0, yourText.Length);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

as of VS2023 please code below:

```
 Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFileName);
```

then load will not raises an error...