# Converting combining diacritics to simple utf

Tags: c#, encoding, diacritics

I have a problem when inserting a string to database due to some encoding issues.

String source is a external rss feed.
In web browser it looks ok. Even in debugger the text appears to be ok.
If I copy the strong to notedpad, the result is also ok.

[image: accented]

But in notepad++ was possible to see that string is using combining characters.
If changing to ansii, both combined appears.
e.g.

á  is displayed as a´

(In notepad++ is is like having two chars, on over the other. I even can select ... half of the char)

[image]

I googled a lot and tried very different approach to this problem.
I really want to find a clever way of convert string with combining diacritics to simple utf8 database compatible ones.

Any help?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you paste the actual string here?

Comment: Sure... "Diálogos sobre cinema português e o cinema do mundo na Gulbenkian"   You can only select half of the char in notepad++.

Comment: The reason for this behaviour is that NotePad++ does not use the right encoding in your computer (not sure why, you have to take a look at its configuration). According to the most voted answer in this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398621/system-text-encoding-getencodingiso-8859-1-throws-platformnotsupportedexcept), you should use the 1252 encoding. I did a test and did work (weird symbols with my default encoding and á when using this one). This is the reason for the weird NotePad++ behaviour but not sure what you want to accomplish, can you please explain it better?

Comment: I found that the problem is some strings from feed are using  combining diacritics.
The char á is &#769;
But we can also get combining ´+a using &#225; (wich is a combining ´) after a leter a.
I need to find a way of way of convert this combining diacritics to simple entities.

Comment: Any look with this? I have a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
output.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC)
```

This little test gave 3, 2, 3. The middle string is correctly combining A and it's diacritic into a single UTF-8 character

```
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(("A\u0302")));    
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(("A\u0302").Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC)));
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(("T\u0302").Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC)));
```

Answer (score 0):

My Mac can solve this running the following Command in Terminal:

iconv -f utf-8-mac -t utf-8 inputfile >outputfile

Comment: He was looking for a way to do this pragmatically I believe